# Hide a Div based on another Div's class

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hide

Trying to hide a div based on another div

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {(

if($("p").hasClass('.out-of-stock')) {
$('#enquiry').hide();
}

});

</script>
```

however it is not working it doesn't hide

Live site at - http://trent-art.co.uk/shop/william-atherton-christmas-around-the-corner/

Trying to hide the submit best offer button if the item is out of stock.

Comment: remove a dot from `.out-of-stock` so it would be `if($("p").hasClass('out-of-stock'))`

Comment: thanks tried this and not working - can see live site here - http://trent-art.co.uk/shop/william-atherton-christmas-around-the-corner/ - want to hide the submit offer button if the item is out of stock with <p class="out-of-stock">

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Have you noticed the syntax error in the Javascript console? You have an extra `(` after `function() {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

if($('#foamy').hasClass('out-of-stock')) {
$('#enquiry').hide();
}

});

</script>
```

gave the p an ID!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove the "." in the .hasClass() method.

Second: Have you try with replace .is('.out-of-stock') instead .hadClass('.out-of-stock)?

Third: Do you want that the .hide() actions runs just on the DOM ready?

You code simply run at the document ready than stop. When the document is ready, the script check if your `<p>` tag has the class "out-of-stock" and after this, it never look again it.

If you want that the check on the class is always running, you need to play with events, so .trigger() and .on().